# Query to update a SQL table column from datetime to minutes and milliseconds

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, insert-update

I'm using SQLite browser, I'm trying to find a query that can update my table from:

Table is called main

```
|  |time_one            |time_two|
| 1| 2016-08-21 07:01:04|  |
| 2| 2016-08-21 08:01:03|  |
| 3| 2016-08-17 09:11:54|  |
| 4| 2016-08-18 11:01:59|  |
| 5| 2016-08-19 12:01:04|  |
| 6| 2016-08-20 01:01:04|  |
```

The result I'm looking for is the minute, second and millisecond:

```
|  |time_one            |time_two|
| 1| 2016-08-21 07:01:04|   01:04|
| 2| 2016-08-21 08:01:03|   01:03|
| 3| 2016-08-17 09:11:54|   11:54|
| 4| 2016-08-18 11:01:59|   01:59|
| 5| 2016-08-19 12:01:04|   01:04|
| 6| 2016-08-20 01:01:04|   01:04|
```

This is the function I used to show the time is

```
Select strftime('%M:%f', time_1)
From main
;
```

Now I just want to update time_2 with what is shown from the above command so I can group the ones with the same minutes and seconds together.

Comment: Well, what RDBMS are you using? `mysql` , `sql-server` or `sqlite`? Isn't it just `sqlite` ?

Comment: Sqlite i'm guessing not sure. I'm not very technical =/. Got really stuck so came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that computation into the [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

```
UPDATE main SET time_2 = strftime('%M:%f', time_1);
```